# SQL Server 2008 - Query which matches both conditions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to find customer's (CustomerID) that have both 1 and 4 for remaining weeks. I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT  o.CustomerID, oi.RemainingWeeks
FROM    Orders o INNER JOIN
        OrderItems oi ON o.OrderID = oi.OrderID 
WHERE   (oi.OrderItemStatusID = 1) AND (oi.RemainingWeeks IN (1, 4)) 
ORDER BY o.CustomerID, oi.RemainingWeeks
```

This finds customers who have 1 for remaining weeks or 4 but not ones that have both. Do I need to modify my join to make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [relational division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/) problem. The way to solve it via aggregates is

```
SELECT  o.CustomerID
FROM    Orders o INNER JOIN
        OrderItems oi ON o.OrderID = oi.OrderID 
WHERE   (oi.OrderItemStatusID = 1) AND (oi.RemainingWeeks IN (1, 4)) 
GROUP BY o.CustomerID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT oi.RemainingWeeks) = 2
ORDER BY o.CustomerID
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the link. I like the aggregate method the best for use with other operations I'm performing in the query.

Answer (score 6):

The key thing to realise is that there's never going to be a single row from `OrderItems` that has RemainingWeeks equal to both 1 and 4. So you need to involve multiple rows somehow. You might achieve this through aggregates, or just performing a second join:

```
SELECT  o.CustomerID, oi1.RemainingWeeks,oi2.RemainingWeeks
FROM    Orders o INNER JOIN
        OrderItems oi1 ON o.OrderID = oi1.OrderID INNER JOIN
        OrderItems oi2 ON o.OrderID = oi2.OrderID
WHERE   (oi1.OrderItemStatusID = 1) AND (oi1.RemainingWeeks =1) AND
        (oi2.OrderItemStatusID = 1) AND (oi2.RemainingWeeks =4) 
ORDER BY
     o.CustomerID, oi1.RemainingWeeks,oi2.RemainingWeeks
```

Comment: +1 yup, you're right - answered too quick, before brain could process question :-)

Comment: Since you are using SQL 2008 you can also use INTERSECT (one of the few real world times I have ever seen it be useful).